# HP DL360 power supply have different firmware and coupled with that the PDU supplying power tripped. Could different power supply firmware cause this

Tags: hp-proliant, power-supply-unit, firmware

We have a HP DL 360 Gen 8 server with two power supplies. Each of them have a different firmware, one of them is running ver 1 and the other is running ver 2. The PDU supplying power to them tripped so can any one confirm if the firmware difference caused this issue.

Answer (score 1):

HP ProLiant Gen8 power supplies *do* have firmware revisions.

Here's a screenshot from the ILO4 interface:

*Note the Model, Spare and Firmware fields...*
[image]

Can you provide the same information from your server's ILO?

Answer (score 0):

The different firmware levels would not cause this. Also, there is no reason that faults in power supplies would cause a PDU to *trip*.
You should look into your PDU.

To protect yourself from issues on a PDU, you should plug each power supply into separate PDUs. This is the reason you would use multiple power supplies in a single device.

Answer (score -2):

If you really want to ensure that all firmware is at the latest level, I suggest you boot the [SPP](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5104018) DVD.  This will allow you to flash all components who's firmware can take an upgrade.  Give that a shot and see if it changes anything.